# how to set response when i am using IActionResult in return type with error message?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

[image]

when try block send error to catch block it throw and response I got at frontend was `{status:'error',error:500}`.

Please explain me what is going when I Re-throw in catch block.
Is .NET is set response when I re-throw?

I want to set status message. how can I do?

Comment: Share your code snippet instead of screenshot, so that your issue can be investigated faster.

Comment: You write only throw and for this get error in frontend. you need return of example `return BadRequest("request is incorrect");`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because code is added as a picture not as text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set status message. how can I do?

Well, you can bind custom status inside `BadRequest()` or Any other response class result. For instance:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadAttachedFile()
        {
            try
            {
                //Your code 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return BadRequest(new { StatusMessage = "Your Messaage", StatusCode = 400 });
            }

       
    }
```

**Note:** Here `StatusMessage`, you can even concat your `ex` message as well. Can introduce new custom error class. You can also skip `StatusCode = 400` because `BadRequest` itself will return that code but if you want to fetch easily from your frontend you can set as well.

**Output:**

In your frontend you would get the response as following:

```
{
    "statusMessage": "Your Messaage",
    "statusCode":  400
}
```

In addition, you can always customize your response class based on your requirement.

[image]